# Linking a Static Library built with arm-none-eabi- in Keil uVision Project

Tags: c, embedded, keil, stm32f4

I was trying to add the `Helix MP3 decoder` to my embedded project for almost couple of days, but because the library was built with `gcc toolchain`, I had plenty of issues compiling under `Keil uVision`.

I thought the only viable option would be creating a static lib.a file with `gcc` based toolchain and having that linked with `ArmLink` in `uVision`. Unfortunately, that did not work for me either. After linking/including the library I created with `gcc` in my Keil `uVision` project, I get over a dozen of errors from the linker like this one:

```
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object mp3dec.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
```

I tried to add the following flag to the compiler: `--wchar32`, but that caused the linker to complain about something else:

```
STM32F407_MPMB\STM32F407_MPMB.axf: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching buffers.o(.bss).

STM32F407_MPMB\STM32F407_MPMB.axf: Error: L6407E: Sections of aggregate size 0x6ac8 bytes could not fit into .ANY selector(s).
```

I'm not very familiar with the linker scripts/options, memory sections, scatter file, but would love to learn about it if that helps!

Anyways, I have no problem getting things done with the Eclipse-Based `gcc` toolchain, however, I started to use Keil `uVision` for several projects recently and would like to stick with it for this one, at least for some time.

Comment: I afraid it is a trap. Just rewrite it. If you do not have c sources it IMO mission impossible, and even if you link it is very likely to do not work

Comment: Yeah, I started to give up. So far, my best bet would be to turn back to the Eclipse IDE and gcc to move forward.

Comment: As you already worked with gcc: Why use Keil at all? gcc is as good at least; ARM contributes code to gcc as well. If you don't like that bloat of Eclipse, use a different IDE; a good text-editor plus a common Linux shell is sufficient and IMO as productive.

Comment: @Olaf why? What is wrong with Eclipse. IMO very good. PS command line gdb is very convenient and productive :D   Why Keil? Many companies spent fortunes on it and force to use it :) I had to use it couple of months ago as it was my client requirement

Comment: Your second error suggests you don't have enough memory.  If you're using the demo version of Keil for ARM, it only supports 32KB.  The .bss is trying to link a buffer of ~27KB, leaving only 5.4K for program and initalized data.

Comment: The paid for tools by Keil also produce denser code (from my past investigations).  I am re-investigating this topic currently, though, so maybe I'll have a different tune to sing in a few weeks.

Comment: @Russ Schultz any examples? I have not noticed any significant differences.

Comment: @RussSchultz: From my experience this is long time gone. It depends heavily on optimisation and gcc version. As always, it is a tradeof between speed and size. COnsidering gcc is developed by much more people and often new techniques are implemented in gcc for testing first, I'd doubt Keil can keep up the pace. Some projects might see a minor increase here or there, I'd say statistically it is balanced since some years.

Comment: @RussSchultz - IMO density of code (if there is any difference of course) is not the issue nowadays. $3 uCs have 256K + flash.

Comment: @PeterJ_01  Depends on what you're working on.   Every embedded project in my career has had feature requirements that outstripped its memory availability.  Of course, I work in deeply embedded custom ASICs and consumer electronics where pennies per part make or break the sale and you can't just up the memory without a 6 month delay and another several million dollars of capital outlay.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 last I checked, Keil was about 10% smaller than GCC, though that was at least 6 years ago I checked.  Like I said, I'm in the process of doing code density analysis for varying cores and compilers so my tune may change by the end of it.

Comment: @Olaf In fact, I kept resisting that Keil thing and its ugly editor for so long until I found myself forced to use it for several projects. I always enjoyed working with Eclipse and I still have the AC6 workbench on Windows and Linux boxes, but configuring the dubugger, printf() redirect over ITM, along with several other issues, made Eclipse a little bit annoying and time consuming for me. Besides, CMSIS native drivers are really a great addition and I found them much easier to adopt to any project in comparison to those of HAL and SPL.

Comment: @RussSchultz: No, I have MDK-Pro

Comment: The funny thing now is, after I spent a lot of time to move the project and its dependencies to Eclipse, the linker now throws these errors: .rodata' will not fit in region `FLASH' ,  region `FLASH' overflowed by 3251536 bytes. With that being said, the size of my code now is bigger when compiled with gcc? Heap size is 0x400 and Stack size is 0x200.

Comment: @EmbeddedMusic FWIW, MDK-Pro acts like the evaluation version if your licensing isn't set up correctly.  It sounds like something else is wrong if your flash is overflowing by 3MB, though ;)

Comment: @RussSchultz: The flash overflow had nothing to do with MDK-Pro. I had no problem compiling it under Keil uVision, but the overflow took place on the Eclipse/gcc compiled project.

Comment: @Olaf: Yep, I'm not talking about CMSIS by it's own. Keil uVision has an option among its Run-Time Environment called: "CMSIS Driver". It has APIs for almost all peripherals and I have built several projects based on those drivers without the need to any HAL/SPL driver. I believe they were written by ARM. Tak a look here: http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Driver/html/index.html

Comment: I have just changed the compiler path in Eclipse to a newer version I have downloaded earlier,  gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update, and now the project compiles without any issue. I believe there was a probem in my linker bin, but how the flash overflowed by more than 3 MBs when the linker script defines that according to my uC?

Comment: @Olaf: I totally agree with you. But different scenarios call for different configurations. But IMHO, FatFs and SD/MMC card drivers in this Keil based API are much more robust and less troublesome. I don't know about others. I still have big portion of my other projects depending on HAL CubeMx generated code. Anyways, this "of-the-shelf" thing sometimes makes much more sense than spending hours, perhaps days, configuring an IDE, adding a library, or porting one.

Comment: @Olaf: I think so. But I did not bring the IDEs to the surface anyways!

Comment: Why do you feel confined to a pre-compiled library?  The source is available - your life will probably be far easier if you build everything with the same compiler, or else keep the points on interaction between two completely independent projects to a very small and explicitly defined number.